# How to make TableRow right-to-left

Tags: android, right-to-left, android-tablelayout, tablerow

How can I add views to `TableRow` right-to-left? the default mode is left-to-right. I tried `android:gravity="right"` and `android:layout_gravity="right"` inside both `TableLayout` and `TableRow` but didn't work.
for example:

```
<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:layoutDirection="rtl"
    android:stretchColumns="*" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:layoutDirection="rtl">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Medium Text" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

the result is button1 at the left and textView1 at the right but I need vice versa .

Comment: Please post your XML code and I can help.

Comment: I'm doing it dynamically

Comment: You mean pragmatically in Java?

Comment: yes, but it doesn't matter , both XML and dynamic type can't handle RTL adding views. this is my question , how can I do this

Comment: Ideally you wan't to choose one or the other. As you are creating your view both pragmatically and in XML they may be coinciding with each other therefore creating issues. You really need to post the code or your not really going to get an answer.

Comment: Come on :D done j4u ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ViewCompat.setLayoutDirection(tableRow,ViewCompat.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your answer is simple. As with any table the first entry you chose will appear first, in your case button1, you need this to be TextView for it to be placed before the button1.

```
<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:layoutDirection="rtl"
    android:stretchColumns="*" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:layoutDirection="rtl">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Medium Text" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" />


    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Comment: You completely misunderstood my question. "first" is where? right or left? :) the default is LTR , I need RTL dude. I told you that I'm doing this dynamically , this XML is just an example

Comment: If you check the XML I have provided then button1 appears to the right and the text is now at the left, as you stated you wanted?

Comment: :| I don't want to change the order of adding views dude! consider I have an array of views from index 0 to n , I want to add view[0] to the right of the TableRow not view[n]

Comment: You need to clarify your question more then. You are never going to get an answer if you don't post the correct source code, that's not just me that will be the same for anyone on here.

Comment: Like I said post the Java code, then expect an answer.

Comment: It was pretty clear to me sorry I dont have answer, im looking for the same thing